# Paintjobs Colors

Tags: paint

I have a 1983 miyata 310 Sport Touring bicycle.
After searching the internet , It has a dark platinum on the frame. I'm trying to find some type of touchup paint that will match the original dark platinum paint on the frame.
 Maybe you know where i could find this color paint.
Thank You.

Comment: You could try to look for automotive touchup (maybe go to a local body shop to see if they can find a similar color, or cut a sample and send it to a service that does touchup paints). Or check another (regular) paint supplier; their scanner machine (depending on type) might be able to match something (or possibly a swatch).  Or, just let it be. As far as I know, no bicycle manufacturer makes touchup paints.

Comment: You can also try someplace that sells a large variety of nail polish.

Comment: If you really want a flawless paint finish, you'll have to repaint the whole frame.

Comment: What @ArgentiApparatus said.  Even if you find the exact original paint colour, it won't match now because the paint on the frame will have aged/faded/discoloured.

Comment: @Batman My BMC Teamelite came with a tiny bottle of touch up paint.  Agreed on the automotive paint though - have successfully used that on my charge cooker to touch up a couple of scrapes after I fell off on some oil

Comment: Could you put a decal/sticker over the area as an alternative ?

Comment: @AndyP - thats interesting. Criggie - they do sell color matching vinyl for cars; works well for metalics on small areas vs touchup paint. Might be something to pursue.

Answer (score 4):

Just as an FYI Testors model paint is a good option.

I have used it on my bike and was able to match every color on my Trek (Dnister Black - Testors Graphite Black Metallic, Viper Red - Testors Gloss Red, Gloss Black, Flat Black). Fortunately, I have only had to use it on a few pencil tip size nicks. You can find it at most craft stores in the US like Michael's, Hobby Lobby, etc for less than $5.00.

I have found usually a cheap precision paint brush, a steady hand, and a bit of patience can result in some really good results.

[image]

vs.

[image]

Just eyeballing your bike frame color from ebay it looks like Testors silver without metal flake may match well (Best bet is to hold the bottle next to the bike which is what I did before using it on my frame).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As Batman says in comments - there are automotive paint stores, depending on where you live, that have a hand held tool that will scan your paint, faded and all, and identify the correct color to match your bike. They use the information from the scanner to mix a color for your bike.

They can make you a can of spray paint or a touch up bottle. in 2015 US dollars they charged me $20 for a can of spray paint.

There are websites that offer custom matching services, [myperfectcolor.com](https://www.myperfectcolor.com/) is one example (not a recommendation) of a company that will work with you to match your color and then create a spray can with your color.

There are also companies that offer bicycle frame touch up services if you'd rather not do the work yourself.